# Conditionally skip flow using akka streams

Tags: akka, akka-stream, akka-http

I'm using akka streams and I have a segment of my graph that I need to conditionally skip because the flow can't handle certain values. Specifically, I have a flow that takes a string and makes http requests, but the server can't handle the case when the string is empty. But I need to just return an empty string instead. Is there a way of doing this without having to go through the http request knowing it will fail? I basically have this:

```
val source = Source("1", "2", "", "3", "4")
val httpRequest: Flow[String, HttpRequest, _]
val httpResponse: Flow[HttpResponse, String, _]
val flow = source.via(httpRequest).via(httpResponse)
```

The only thing I can think of doing is catching the 400 error in my httpResponse flow and returning a default value. But I'd like to be able to avoid the overhead of hitting the server for a request I know is going to fail beforehand.

Comment: Your example does not compile.  The output of httpRequest is of type HttpRequest and the input of httpResponse is of type HttpResponse therefore they cannot be chained together with 'via'.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Viktor Klang's solution is concise and [elegant](https://www.google.com/search?q=beautiful%20mind%20writing%20on%20glass%20images).  I just wanted to demonstrate an alternative using Graphs.

You can split your source of Strings into two streams and filter one stream for valid Strings and the other stream for invalid Strings.  Then merge the results ("[cross the streams](https://www.google.com/search?q=ghostbusters%20cross%20the%20streams%20images)").

Based on the [documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/2.0-M1/scala/stream-graphs.html#constructing-flow-graphs):

```
val g = RunnableGraph.fromGraph(FlowGraph.create() { implicit builder: FlowGraph.Builder[Unit] =>
  import FlowGraph.Implicits._

  val source = Source(List("1", "2", "", "3", "4"))
  val sink : Sink[String,_] = ???

  val bcast = builder.add(Broadcast[String](2))
  val merge = builder.add(Merge[String](2))

  val validReq =   Flow[String].filter(_.size > 0)
  val invalidReq = Flow[String].filter(_.size == 0)

  val httpRequest: Flow[String, HttpRequest, _] = ???
  val makeHttpCall: Flow[HttpRequest, HttpResponse, _] = ???
  val httpResponse: Flow[HttpResponse, String, _] = ???
  val someHttpTransformation = httpRequest via makeHttpCall via httpResponse

  source ~> bcast ~> validReq ~> someHttpTransformation ~> merge ~> sink
            bcast ~>      invalidReq                    ~> merge
  ClosedShape
})
```

Note: this solution splits the stream, therefore the Sink may process String value results in a different order than is expected based on the inputs.

Comment: Yes! That's another option when you are OK with reordering of the operations (as the http-flow and the non-http operate in parallel)

Comment: This is perfect. i didn't think about parallel filters. Good point about ordering, but the akka-http's request flow is unordered anyway (at least the https pool one is)

Answer (score 17):

You could use `flatMapConcat`:

(Warning: was never compiled, but you'll get the gist of it)

```
val source = Source("1", "2", "", "3", "4")
val httpRequest: Flow[String, HttpRequest, _]
val httpResponse: Flow[HttpResponse, String, _]
val makeHttpCall: Flow[HttpRequest, HttpResponse, _]
val someHttpTransformation = httpRequest via makeHttpCall via httpResponse
val emptyStringSource = Source.single("")
val cleanerSource = source.flatMapConcat({
  case "" => emptyStringSource
  case other => Source.single(other) via someHttpTransformation
})
```

Comment: Viktor, could create `Source.single` for each "filter" impact negatively the stream in any way?

Comment: pardon my off topic question, but is `map({ case _ => ??? })` preferred to just `map{ case _ => ??? }` ? I tend not to nest braces inside parentheses unless necessary (in longer parameter lists). My ex-colleague used to do this `({ case _ => ???})` and I used to remove the redundant parens...

Comment: I tend to use parenthesis when I use explicit dots.